# How to get all functions of es6 class instance

Tags: javascript, class, methods, ecmascript-6, es6-class

For example, I have some class with some methods:

```
class SomeClass() {
    someMethod1() {
    }
    someMethod2() {
    }
}
```

Can I get all function names of this class instance?

```
Object.keys(new SomeClass())
```

gives me an empty array.

I want to get array like `['someMethod1', 'someMethod2']`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to call [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) on the `prototype` property of the class.

```js
class Test {
  methodA() {}
  methodB() {}
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Test.prototype))
```

Note that this also includes the constructor, but you can easily exclude it if you want:

```js
class Test {
  methodA() {}
  methodB() {}
}

console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Test.prototype)
    .filter(x => x !== 'constructor')
)
```

Comment: I know the question didn't call for it, but just for reference sake, this won't show static or inherited methods.